# Hide sub-component in components generated with map() in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a todo app.
When a task is clicked

```
setState({displayTaskMenu: true})
```

is called,

but I also need to hide the taskMenu on all the other Task components where displayTaskMenu is true.

What is the correct way of doing this with React?

This is the render method of Task component:

```
render() {
    let { task } = this.props;

    return (
        <div onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
            <div>
                {task.label}

                {this.state.displayTaskMenu && (<TaskMenu />)}

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Tasks are sorted by days, and the render of Day component is:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.state.dayStyle}>
            <span style={this.state.dateStyle}>{this.props.date}</span>
            <h1>{this.props.day}</h1>

            {this.props.tasks &&
                this.props.tasks.map(
                    (task, i) => <Task key={i} task={task}/>
                )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there a parent component that holds all the `Task` components? (I'm assuming the code you posted was from the `Task` component.) If so, can we see it?

Comment: Updated  the question, yes it is from the Task component. Task's parent is the Day component, as tasks are being sorted to each days in the week.

Comment: So, when a `Task` from the `Day` component is clicked, you want all other `Task` components to hide the `TaskMenu`? Am I comprehending this correctly?

Comment: Yes. you do indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only one `Task` component should open their `TaskMenu`, the `Day` component needs to keep track of which `Task` it is by using state. So, the `Day` component should pass in a custom `onClick` function to each `Task` an update its state.

`Day` component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.state.dayStyle}>
            <span style={this.state.dateStyle}>{this.props.date}</span>
            <h1>{this.props.day}</h1>

            {this.props.tasks &&
                this.props.tasks.map(
                    (task, i) => <Task 
                                  key={i}
                                  task={task}
                                  displayMenu={this.state.displaying == i}
                                  onClick={ () => this.setState({displaying: i}) }/>
                )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

`Task` component:

```
render() {
    let { task } = this.props;

    return (
        <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            <div>
                {task.label}

                {this.props.displayMenu && (<TaskMenu />)}

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Using this approach, you don't need the `toggleMenu` function in the `Task` component anymore.